# Paradox error on CreateTable

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, bde

I was creating table during execution, however at the creation of the table, (see my code)

```
procedure CreateTempTable(pDataBaseName,pSessionName:String);
begin
  //-------create "TempTable" 
  TempTable:=TTable.Create(application);
  With TempTable Do
  begin
    //-------set false in "Active"
    Active := False;
    //-------name of Session
    SessionName:=pSessionName;
    //-------name of DataBase.
    DatabaseName :=pDataBaseName;
    Filtered := True;
    //-------name of table
    TableName := 'TempTabl.DB';
    //-------paradox type
    TableType := ttParadox;
    //-------if the table is already exists
    if TempTable.Exists then
      //-------delete the table
      TempTable.DeleteTable;
    //-------create 2 fields "Field1" & "Field2"
    with FieldDefs do
    begin
      Clear;
      with AddFieldDef do
      begin
        DataType := ftFloat;
        Name := 'Field1';
      end;
      with AddFieldDef do
      begin
        DataType := ftFloat;
        Name:='Field2';
      end;
    end;

    //-------Create table
    CreateTable;  // Here where the exception bursts off
  end;
end;
```

an exception is raised, which is: "Table is open, Table does not exist".
so what is exactly the problem, is it open or doesnot exist?

This is the exception:
[image]

Comment: Since you're dealing with such old things, did you try the code with a short and simple path, like `C:\Temp`? See if it makes a difference.

Comment: It's a Paradox table; it's open *and* it does not exist. ;-)

Comment: My answer could help you?

Comment: Thank you, better late than never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(inside `With TempTable Do`) There is no need to delete the `TempTabl.DB` explicit. Is overwritten by `CreateTable` anyway.

To test if the table is not being used by other components in the IDE, you can try to delete the file `TempTabl.DB`.

**CreateTempTable** is now a function CreateTempTable(pDataBaseName,pSessionName:String):Boolean;
So you can better handle errors.

Tested with **delphi 5** and **RAD Studio 2007**.

```
function CreateTempTable(pDataBaseName,pSessionName:String):Boolean;
begin
result:=false;
// assume pDataBaseName=directory, or change it 
if FileExists(pDataBaseName+'TempTabl.DB') then begin
   if NOT DeleteFile(pDataBaseName+'TempTabl.DB') then begin
      showMessage('Table opened by another part of the IDE');
      exit;
   end;
end;

TempTable:=TTable.Create(application);
With TempTable Do
begin
Active := False;
SessionName:=pSessionName;
DatabaseName :=pDataBaseName;
//Filtered := True;
TableName := 'TempTabl.DB';
TableType := ttParadox;
with FieldDefs do
begin
  Clear;
  with AddFieldDef do
  begin
    DataType := ftFloat;
    Name := 'Field1';
  end;
  with AddFieldDef do
  begin
    DataType := ftFloat;
    Name:='Field2';
  end;
end;
CreateTable;
result:=true;
end;
end;
```